# Is there a way to inject UseCase in ViewModel created with ViewModelProvider and custom LifecycleOwner?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, viewmodel, android-lifecycle, dagger-hilt

I am creating system Android application.

I don't have activity, only the service. I created my custom class to inflate view and to show it. I want to access ViewModel in that class. ViewModel should call UseCase. ViewModel should be aware of that custom lifecycle.
I am using Hilt to provide UseCase.

I tried instantiating view model this way:

`viewModel: TestViewModel = ViewModelProvider(myLifecycleOwner)[TestViewModel::class.java]`

because I need to provide my lifecycle owner.

My ViewModel class looks like this:

`@HiltViewModel class TestViewModel @Inject constructor(private var useCase: UseCase) : ViewModel()`

I got exception:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class TestViewModel
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class has no zero argument constructor